# Flask - each HTTP request does not seem to be a new and independent request. Why is that?

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple Flask endpoint set up, like this:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

languages = ['Python', 'Java', 'C++', 'Ruby', 'C']

@app.route('/')
def index():
    lang = languages.pop(0)
    return 'Language = {}'.format(lang)
```

When I look at that endpoint in a browser, it displays 'Language = Python' on first request (expected). If I reload the page it displays 'Language = Java' (unexpected). If I reload again it displays 'Language = C++'.

The way I understood HTTP, each request is a new and fresh request to the server, so I would have expected the browser to display 'Language = Python' every time I reloaded the page.

What is going on here? 
Why does the Flask endpoint seem to remember the state of the 'languages' list from the previous request?
 I'd prefer it didn't do that! Thanks.

Comment: Move `languages` inside of `index()`.

Comment: The above is just a stripped down version of my code to illustrate the issue. I need to access the 'languages' list in other functions. If I move it into index I won't be able to do that will I?

Comment: You can make a class to hold `languages` and group related functions into that class. Then in `index()` create an object of that class and use it.

Answer (score 0):

pop() is an inbuilt function in Python that removes and returns last value from the list or the given index value.
'languages' is the list in your flask app and when you call pop the element at index 0 is removed. This is why next time you do the HTTP call you get the next element. The 'languages' list is the '**state**' of your Flask module. The code below will return 'Python' always.

```
lang = languages[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really address my question/problem. I know how pop() works. My question is, WHY does each new HTTP request seem to remember the previous request. I didn't set anything to make it remember the previous state. I'm hoping someone with deeper Flask knowledge will enlighten me and explain 1) why this is happening, and 2) how I can prevent each new request "remembering" the previous request.

Comment: Once the code is loaded, the 'languages'  list is populated and stay in memory. So its not about deeper Flask understanding.. It is about understanding what is going on when the module is loaded. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Not clearer really. You are just asserting it's that way. But as I mentioned, I thought HTTP requests by default do not remember state, so I would have imagined each new request would see the original "languages" list. Can you point to something in the docs that explains what you're referring to?

Comment: Let me try again. Imagine you have a Flask app backed by a DB. In this DB you have a table named 'languages'. Each time the client does HTTP GET to / a record is fetched from the table and deleted. So in this example the 'state' is kept in a DB. In your example the 'state' is kept in a list.

Comment: Not sure why you think that sheds any light -- of course a database will preserve state. I'll try again also: where in the Flask docs does it state that any variables you set will be remembered across HTTP requests? Where does it state that additional requests will have knowledge of previous requests (contrary to common knowledge regarding HTTP)? I'm not saying that's not the case, I'm just asking where the Flask docs indicate that, because it would be helpful to read about that. As it is the behavior is anomalous to everyday HTTP understanding.

Comment: It’s not about HTTP nor about Flask. It is just the fact that you have a global variable that is populated  when your code loads and stays there.

Comment: Yes, the question remains, WHY does it stay there. It IS about Flask, because if I have a python file mytest.py like `a=1  print(a)  a=2` it will always display '1' each time I run it. That code has a global variable in it yet each time the code is run it is reset to the value at the start of the code. WHY does Flask not operate in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Python is usually not loaded every time at each request. With that in mind, note how your `languages` list is declared in the global scope. This means every request will share the same instance. Since lists are **mutable** (unlike tuples), this is a recipe for disaster, unless you're doing it on purpose.

There's use cases for it though, like every request accessing the same database connection for instance (if the connection is thread safe).

Basically you have to be aware of what's being "born" inside of the request scope, and what belongs to the global scope and is shared among requests.

Comment: "note how your languages list is declared in the global scope. This means every request will share the same instance."
Why? How does global scope imply each new request knows about (previous changes to) variables in global scope?